# arduino keyboard does not release cause freeze

Tags: arduino

When I upload this script, my normal keyboard is not usable anymore and I think the right alt key is stuck in, even if I unplug the arduino the problem is still there.

The goal of this is to have a push to talk pedal for teamspeak. I was able to get around the problem using another script that passes itself as a controller but this causes other issues with games since they think I am using a controller all of a sudden.

From what I understand, this code should loop, while the pin is active, it should simulate the right alt key being pressed. When it is done it should release all key pressed by the script. It is hard to debug this since whenever I upload it I have to spend 10 minutes to be able to use my keyboard again.

Any help would be appreciated. Extra info, I am using the arduino leonardo.

```
#include <Keyboard.h>

void setup() {
  // Initialize Button Pins
  Keyboard.begin();
  pinMode(9, INPUT_PULLUP);

}

void loop() {

 Keyboard.releaseAll();

  while (digitalRead(9) == HIGH) {
    Keyboard.press(KEY_RIGHT_ALT);
    delay(500);
  }
  delay(500);

  Keyboard.releaseAll();
  // wait for new window to open:
}
```

Comment: please define *" is not usable anymore"*. Does it still not work if `Keyboard.press(KEY_RIGHT_ALT);` is commented out?

Comment: None of the keys I try work but now that I think about it that is what right alt would do for most of them.

Comment: I will try that and come back with answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Note:** without the actual hardware at my disposal for some tests, it is hard to know what is going wrong, so I'll try to review your code looking for possible point of failures.

---

According to the [docs](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Reference/KeyboardPress), `press()` *functions as if a key were pressed and held down on the keyboard*.

According to these other [docs](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Tutorial/DigitalPins), `INPUT_PULLUP` *effectively inverts the behavior of the `INPUT` mode, where `HIGH` means the sensor is off, and `LOW` means the sensor is on.*

---

Therefore, a simple modification would be:

```
#include <Keyboard.h>

void setup() {
  // Initialize Button Pins
  Keyboard.begin();
  pinMode(9, INPUT_PULLUP);    
}

void loop() {
  static bool pressed = false;

  // does the pedal close the circuit with GND?
  if (digitalRead(9) == HIGH) {                // no
    if (pressed) {
      Keyboard.release(KEY_RIGHT_ALT);
      pressed = false;
    }
  } else {                                     // yes
    if (!pressed) {
      Keyboard.press(KEY_RIGHT_ALT);
      pressed = true;
    }
  }

  delay(500); // waste time
}
```

---

Does this code display the same issues?